# Deleting empty cells and selecting cells matching a pattern

Tags: front-end, pattern-matching, notebooks, cells

Is there any way for me to automatically select all cells that are completely empty? You know, those cells that you create but end up cutting what's in them and paste it somewhere else, so after a while you get a bunch of empty cells in your workbook (if you're sloppy as me at least).

My other question is, is there any way for you to automatically select all the cells matching a particular pattern (e.g. if I wanted to delete all cells that have `Select[]` inside), or that have a style (text cells).

Thanks

Comment: Empty is a tricky thing here, there may be a lot of `" "` or `"\n"` and is it empty cell too? You can `NotebookRead` on cells but pattern approach for the content may be tricky to. What you see in notebook does not necessarily indicate unique box structure. But for detecting occurance of `Select` it should be enough.

Comment: You are right, I was only thinking on what I see in a notebook. Indeed, some cells often have "\n" and I don't see those, so maybe the search could be on white space?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

More stable answer, in case of images and stuff evaluated in place in input cells:

```
NotebookDelete /@ Select[Cells[GeneratedCell -> False], StringMatchQ[
    First@
     FrontEndExecute[
      FrontEnd`ExportPacket[NotebookRead@#, "InputText"]],
    (" " | "\t" | "\r" | "\n" | "\[IndentingNewLine]") ...
    ] &
  ]
```

It may be slower than the original one.

---

**Old answer**

Would that be ok?

```
NotebookDelete /@ Select[
     Cells[EvaluationNotebook[], GeneratedCell -> False ],
     StringCount[
       StringJoin @@ Flatten[List @ First[NotebookRead[#]] /. RowBox | BoxData -> List],
       Except[{" ", "\n", "\[IndentingNewLine]"}]] == 0 &
     ]
```

Comment: eh, it works, also on those with multiple paragraphs and stuff!

Comment: @Sosi Great :) good luck then.

Comment: @Kuba, the updated solution doesn't seem to work. it doesn't delete the empty cellls.

Comment: @SaqibAli could you copy an example of such cell's BoxData so I can diagnoze the problem?